# Function is getting only the first variadic argument value right

Tags: c++, variadic-functions

This function should pretty obviously return the minimum float value, but it always returns 0. While debugging, I found out that the `va_arg()` function gets only that 31 right, then it gets some strange numbers, one of them every time being 0.

```cpp
float var_min(int, float, ...);

void main()
{
    cout << var_min(7, 31, 12, 4.5, 9, 22, 69, 8.21);
}

float var_min(int z, float, ...)
{
    int i = 0;
    float min, p;
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, z);
    min = va_arg(ap, float);
    for (i = 1; i < z; i++)
    {
        p = va_arg(ap, float);
        min = (min < p) ? min : p;
    }
    va_end(ap);
    return min;
}
```

Edit: this is the assignment:

> Determine the minimum of a 10 float numbers from a string (implicit values or from the KB) using a function with a variable number of parameters. The first 7 values will be considered initially, next the last 3 and at the end these 2 values.

Comment: Ugh, variadic functions. To C, `31`, `12`, `22` and `69` are not floating-point numbers. They are ints and because the variadc function cannot know its types, they are passed as ints and the vararg macros treats them as ints.

Comment: 4.5 is not float as well. It is double!!

Comment: @P__J__: That's right, but floats are promoted to doubles in variadic arguments. The problem with variadic functions is that it takes longer to explain all the quirks than to rewrite the function in question properly with an array. `:)`

Comment: This would work of course with variadic _templates_ where the compiler knows the actual type of each argument.  Unfortunately, this is one of the areas where the long history and C language legacy of C++ bites the unfortunate programmer.  C++ is all about strong typing and other goodness and it works great ... until you hit one of these C legacies which are _not distinguishable syntactically to the naked eye_.   (Although the `#include` of `varargs.h` or `cstdarg` could possibly serve to clue in someone aware of the issue...)

Comment: When you post code for a debugging question, please always post a [mre], including all the `#include` and `using` statements in your program, so that somebody who wants to help you can copy the code, paste it into a new source file, and compile it without any changes or additions.

Comment: I feel like the tag should be changed from [tag:c++] to [tag:c]. Especially since no one is bringing up the parameter pack.

Comment: BTW, [this page on variadic functions in C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/variadic) and [this page it points to on implicit conversion in C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/conversion#Default_argument_promotions) will help explain what's going on here.  Because in C++ the C rules for C-style variadic functions apply.

Comment: The text of the assignment cannot be taken literally. Presumably “a string” means a sequence of characters. Strings do not contain `float` objects or values; they contain characters. Those characters can be numerals that represent numbers. You can scan the strings to convert those numerals into `float` objects. However, to use C’s variable argument list feature, they must be passed and received as `double` values. `double` must be used in `va_arg`, although its result can be assigned to `float`. I expect the assignment may have been written sloppily and is not strict about using `float`.

Answer (score 1):

To use `va_arg` starting with the second argument, change:

```
float var_min(int z, float, ...)
```

to:

```
float var_min(int z, ...)
```

(If there will always be at least one floating-point argument after `z`, and you wish to include it in the parameter list, then give it a name, initialize `min` from it directly, and change `va_start(ap, z)` to use its name instead of `z`.)

To pass `float` or `double` arguments to a variable-argument function, they must be explicitly of `float` or `double` type; integer types will not be converted to floating-point types, so:

```
var_min(7, 31, 12, 4.5, 9, 22, 69, 8.21);
```

should be:

```
var_min(7, 31., 12., 4.5, 9., 22., 69., 8.21);
```

In variable arguments, `float` arguments are promoted to `double`, so `va_arg(ap, float)` should be `va_arg(ap, double)` in both places it appears, and `float min, p;` should be `double min, p;`.

`void main()` is not a standard declaration for `main`. It could be `int main()`.

Comment: You see,this is part of my homework for uni, and it explicitly says about float values. So there is no way to use float in variadic functions like this? Was it perhaps a little trap?

Comment: @PatyBanana: Edit the question to show the exact text of the assignment. We cannot ascertain the intended meaning from a second-hand description.

Comment: @PatyBanana are you sure the homework actually talks about the `float` data type specifically, and not just about "floating point" types in general?

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes,it's talking about float number,as far as I understand from the assignment. I added it to the question

Comment: @EricPostpischil I did the modifications you told me about but it's still doing the same thing. Should I post an update on the code?